# Problema com links no ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Quando eu adiciono um *link* do tipo `www.google.com?var=1&var=2&var=3` no CKEditor ele automaticamente insere `&amp` deixando o *link* com o seguinte aspecto: `www.google.com?var=1&ampvar=2&ampvar=3`

Alguém já teve esse problema e encontrou a solução?

Answer (score 4):

Segundo [esse thread no suporte do CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/URL-Links-converts-making-URL-invalid), é necessário alterar uma configuração para que os `&` não sejam "escapados" quando dentro de links:

```
CKEDITOR.config.forceSimpleAmpersand = true;
```

Após ativar essa configuração (que também pode ser feita para um editor individual, em vez de globalmente na página) os editores criados não converterão `&` em `&amp;` dentro de links, mas continuarão a fazê-lo no conteúdo normal da página (como esperado). Não sei dizer em que outras circunstâncias esse comportamento também ocorre, se algum.

Comment: Eu encontrei esse arquivo no meu config.js, fiz a alteração e só depois de tudo isso eu descobri que o meu CKEditor foi todo alterado. Ele nem carrega o plugin.js :(

Comment: @MarceloMatzembacher Não entendo... você alterou o fonte do CKEditor? A ideia era colocar a linha acima no seu próprio script.

Comment: Eu não alterei o fonte, apenas estou dando suporte a um produto web que utiliza o CKEditor, e ele foi modificado para não exibir todos os recursos disponíveis.